# are ant attribute name arguments are predefined?

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to run hello world. I am getting an error **"Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute"**

I encountered the error, it's with attribute name="MainClass", when I replaced it with Main-Class it is working fine.

Attribute names are user defined, right? then why i am getting this error?

Here is my code:-

```
    <target name="run" depends="clean,build,jar">
        <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true" />
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>
    <target name="build">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" />
    </target>
    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" >
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="MainClass" value="${main-class}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Here is my output for error part:-

```
sushil@sushil:~/java/hello_world$ ant
Buildfile: /home/sushil/java/hello_world/build.xml

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/sushil/java/hello_world/build

build:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/sushil/java/hello_world/build/classes
    [javac] /home/sushil/java/hello_world/build.xml:39: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /home/sushil/java/hello_world/build/classes

jar:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/sushil/java/hello_world/build/jar
      [jar] Building jar: /home/sushil/java/hello_world/build/jar/hello_world.jar

run:
     [java] Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
     [java] /home/sushil/java/hello_world/build/jar/hello_world.jar
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Main-Class** is a special attribute which serves as the entry point. See the [manifest documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for more information.